# android - ListView не хочет делиться двумя последними айтемами

Tags: android, listview

У меня такая задача: есть список. При нажатии на какой-либо айтем, блокируется прокрутка списка и нажатия. Мне помимо этого надо, чтобы все айтемы кроме нажатого стали наполовину прозрачными. А, когда нажатый айтем выполнит действие, все айтемы лишились прозрачности. Делаю так:

```
for(int x=0; x<lv.getCount(); ;x++){
lv_inspiration.getChildAt(x).setAlpha(0.5f);
}
```

Но игра вылетала. Я добавил код для вывода в лог и понял, что дело обрывается в последних айтемах

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setAlpha(float)' on a null object refere`

Я также вывел в лог количество айтемов, оно было на 2 раза меньше, чем в действительности (количество всегда равно девяти, выдавало 7). Что делать? Айтемов 9, а восьмой и девятый будто пропали. Не предлагайте ставить прозрачность на список, ибо нужен именно эффект прозрачности на всех айтемах, кроме нажатого. Помогите, где рыть? У меня свой адаптер, может там что-то?

Вот слушатель:

```
lv_inspiration.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    ProgressBar pb;
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, final int position, long p4)
    {

        for(int x=0; x<lv_inspiration.getCount(); x++){
            if(x!=position)
            lv_inspiration.getChildAt(x).setAlpha(0.5f);
        }
        lv_inspiration.setEnabled(false);
        lv_inspiration.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
        pb = (ProgressBar)p2.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_item);
        pb.setProgress(0);
        cdt = new CountDownTimer(50000, 200) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(pb.getProgress()!=100)
                pb.setProgress(pb.getProgress()+1);
                else
                onFinish();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                cdt.cancel();
                for(int x=0; x<lv_inspiration.getCount(); x++){
                lv_inspiration.getChildAt(x).setAlpha(1f);
                }

                lv_inspiration.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }.start();
}})
```

Comment: Айтемов, которые не отображаются на экране как бы нет и нельзя получить из них `View`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, я сделал. Сначала всем айтемам даю прозрачность, затем нажатому ее убираю

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте начинать и заканчивать цикл не нулем и общим количеством элементов, а через

```
int startPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int endPosition = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
```

Comment: теперь во как. Если список не крутить, и сразу нажать, то все нормально. Стоит мне прокрутить список вниз, все айтемы, которых до скролла не было видно при нажатии игра вылетает с теми же логами.

Comment: прозрачность для элементов где выставляется? в onClickListener для текущего элемента? и где убирается прозрачность?

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: а где getFirstVisiblePosition() и getLastVisiblePosition()?

Comment: это не подходит. Эти же логи. К тому же, прозрачными становятся не все айтемы, а лишь полностью видимые. Тоесть, на те, что торчат на какую-то часть не ставится прозрачность